# Best way to implement dependency injection for generic class in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, generics, .net-core, dependency-injection

I have a generic class and corresponding interface as follows:

```
public class APIClient<T1, T2> : IApiClient<T1, T2> 
                                            where T1 : class
                                            where T2 : class
{
    public APIClient()
    {

    }

    public async Task<T2> PostToEndPoint(string url, T1 input)
    {
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler();

        using (var httpclient = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            var response = await httpclient.PutAsJsonAsync(url, input);
            var st = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T2>(st);
            return res;
        }
    }
}




public interface IApiClient<T1, T2> where T1 : class
                                    where T2 : class
{
    Task<T2> PostToEndPoint(string url,T1 input);
}
```

I have done the registration as follows:

builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(IApiClient<,>), typeof(APIClient<,>));

There are different apis accepting different input and output models:

Example controller:

```
public class ProjectController : ControllerBase 
{ 
   private readonly IApiClient<classA, classB> _apiCLient1; 
   private readonly IApiClient<classC, classD> _apiCLient2; 
   private readonly IApiClient<classE, classF> _apiCLient3;

   public ProjectController (IApiClient<classA, classB> apiCLient1, IApiClient<classC,           classD> apiCLient2, IApiClient<classE, classF> apiCLient3)
  {
    _apiCLient1 = apiCLient1;
    _apiCLient2 = apiCLient2;
    _apiCLient3 = apiCLient3;
  }
}
```

Is there a better way to handle the above scenario without separate apiClients? Since, different apis are accepting different input models and returning different output models, I am having to create separate apiClients. Please recommend a better way of implementing the above mentioned scenario.

Comment: Why do you need to use seperate apiClients? Can you provide a concrete example instead of fake codes?

Comment: I created separate instances of IApiClient to take care of the different input and output models associated with the different api calls. But I am not sure whether that's the best way of handling this scenario or not - so I posted this question. @shingo

Comment: The problem is how you take care these models. Does this controller have to handle all three models every time? Is it processed one by one, or in parallel? How are instances of the model initialized? Is the result processed uniformly or customized?

Comment: For what it's worth I wouldn't use a generic interface this way. It means that each API client only supports one endpoint. You end up with an interface that doesn't describe what it does very well. This will also cause huge pain when just one endpoint requires a new argument for some unforeseeable reason, that forces you to change the interface, and that forces you to change all of the concrete classes. I recommend checking out [https://github.com/reactiveui/refit](https://github.com/reactiveui/refit). But either way, explicit interfaces are better.

Answer (score 4):

Are the `APIClient` instances different simply because you're providing the different generic types to indicate how to serialize and deserialize, or is there something fundamentally different?

If they're just the generic types, you can simply make the method generic, instead of the object, and pass in a single API object.

Note: I'm assuming the `Toutput` was meant to be `T2`.

```
public class APIClient : IApiClient 
{
    public APIClient()
    {

    }

    public async Task<T2> PostToEndPoint<T1,T2>(string url, T1 input)
        where T1 : class
        where T2 : class
    {
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler();

        using (var httpclient = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            var response = await httpclient.PutAsJsonAsync(url, input);
            var st = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T2>(st);
            return res;
        }
    }
}   

public interface IApiClient
{
    Task<T2> PostToEndPoint<T1,T2>(string url, T1 input)
        where T1 : class
        where T2 : class;
}
```